# How to hide transactions from peers in hyperledger fabric v1

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am trying to build a simple car tracking blockchain app on hyperledger fabric v1.0, much like IBM Carlease demo built back with v0.6.
An overview of my app is

- Manufacturer build the car and sell it to dealer
- dealer sell it to user
- user can use it throughout its life or can sell it to another user
- Manufacturer can track all the cars they manufactured, from start to its current status
- Dealer can only track the cars that he bought from various manufacturers to its current status.
- User can only track car/s he bought, from its manufacturer to the user he sold to, but must not have access to view transactions afterwards.
- And also there is a regulatory authority that can track any car from manufacturer to its current user.

I am having trouble restricting user to view transactions that is performed after he sell the car to another user. How can i achieve this? And where can i implement these restrictions, in chaincode or SDK?

Answer (score 1):

You can implement the restrictions in either SDK or CC. I strongly recommend CC as the only true guarantee.

There are many options to implement. My favorite is something like...

If Invoker == User then retrieve transaction history for mycar where date <= mysolddate, else retrieve all history.